# Dynamic radio buttons not working correctly within html for:each loop in lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-radiogroup

[image]I want to make the radio buttons for the questionnaire, but the radio buttons are behaving like multi-select values instead of single radio buttons.

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Quiz Questionaire" icon-name="action:question_post_action" variant="narrow">
        <form>
        <template for:each={questions} for:item="ques">
            <div key={ques.serial}>
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <div class="slds-box slds-box_small">{ques.serial} {ques.question}
                        <div>
                            <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
                                options={ques.options} 
                                value={value} 
                                type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </form>
    </lightning-card> </template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class QuizQuestionaire extends LightningElement {
    questions = [
        {serial: "Question 1.",
        question: "Which is not the lwc directives?",
        options:[
            {serial:'a',
            label:'<template>',
            value:'<template>'
            },
            {serial:'b',
            label:'<apex>',
            value:'<apex>'
            },
            {serial:'c',
            label:'<p>',
            value:'<p>'
            }],
        answer:"b"
        },
        {serial: "Question 2.",
        question: "Select the file which is not the part of lwc bundle",
        options:[
            {serial:'a',
            label:'.apex',
            value:'.apex'
            },
            {serial:'b',
            label:'.js',
            value:'.js'
            },
            {serial:'c',
            label:'.svg',
            value:'.svg'
            }],
        answer:"a"
        },
        {serial: "Question 3.",
        question: "We can use formula expressions in .html file in lwc components?",
        options:[
            {serial:'a',
            label:'True',
            value:true
            },
            {serial:'b',
            label:'False',
            value:false
            }],
        answer:"b"
        }
    ]
    optionHander(event){
        console.log("resp-->",event.target.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you had a chance to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a radiogroup to work properly, it needs a unique name.

Assuming your questions are unique, use these as the name. Eg:

```
<lightning-radio-group name={ques.question}
    options={ques.options} 
    value={value} 
    type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
```

More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/documentation)

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: Glad to help!!!